# Enrutamiento sale con / al final del URL asp.net WEB FORM

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Al enrutar mi url me sale de la siguiente manera (localmente)

> localhost:7876/Camino

Pero al subirlo me sale asi: (servidor)

> pagina.web.com.pe/Camino/

Quisiera que no salga el ultimo "/" , alguien me podria decir en que falle o tengo que ver? Agradezco su ayuda.
Busqué en algunos foros me dijeron que lo ponga en una carpeta pero no el porqué , o tal porque no tiene https el servidor?

```
namespace LVehicular
{


 public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Código que se ejecuta al iniciarse la aplicación
           // BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
           // AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

    protected void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("Camino",
            "Camino",
            "~/Default.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: He probado tu ejemplo y a mí me funciona perfectamente. La única diferencia es que yo utilizo:     RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Camino", "Camino", "~/Default.aspx");

Comment: Lo probé , ahora me sale con "/" en local.
ahahahah